# pygame projectiles not visable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am new to pygame but not so much to programming, I am having difficulty to have a projectile appear anytime after I press the button. If I hold the button it will work but otherwise I can't get it to display. I do know it is adding it to the coins list because if I put use the print function I can see the coins list but I can't see the objects when drawn otherwise. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Why U NO WORK?")

class throw_coin(object):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, radius):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.hitbox = (self.x-15, self.y-15, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)
        self.vel = 8

    def draw(self, win):
        self.x += self.vel
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        #update hitbox if coin moves
        self.hitbox = (self.x-15, self.y-15, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)
        # draw the hitbox remove later after debug
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (white), self.hitbox, 2)

class player(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 10
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)
        self.coins = []

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
        # update hitbox if player moves
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)
        # draw the hitbox remove later after debug
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (white), self.hitbox, 2)

    def move(self):

       # create a variable that is assigned to any keypress
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and self.x > self.vel:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and self.x < WIDTH - self.width - self.vel:
            self.x += self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.y > self.vel:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_s] and self.y < HEIGHT - self.height - self.vel:
            self.y += self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_g]:
            if len(self.coins) < 100:
                self.coins.append(throw_coin((0,255,0), 500, 300, 15))
                for gold in self.coins:
                    gold.draw(window)


user = player(30, 300-32, 64,64)
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    # exit the program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    user.draw(window)
    user.move()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Could you show us your relevant code? Thanks :D

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that in. Just updated it.

Comment: Ah, your drawing code is only run when 'g' is pressed because the `for gold in self.coins:` is inside `if keys[pygame.K_g]`. Just move it outside that and you'll be "golden" :)

Comment: Thanks. For the help. I relised this just as you answered. lol.

Answer (score 2):

Just figuered it out. Here is the new code. Thanks for everyone who stopped by and tried to help.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Why U NO WORK?")
def redraw_game():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    for gold in user.coins:
        gold.draw(window)
    user.draw(window)
    user.move()
    pygame.display.update()
class throw_coin(object):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, radius):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.hitbox = (self.x-15, self.y-15, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)
        self.vel = 8

    def draw(self, win):
        self.x += self.vel
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        #update hitbox if coin moves
        self.hitbox = (self.x-15, self.y-15, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)
        # draw the hitbox remove later after debug
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (white), self.hitbox, 2)

class player(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 10
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)
        self.coins = []

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
        # update hitbox if player moves
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)
        # draw the hitbox remove later after debug
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (white), self.hitbox, 2)

    def move(self):

        # create a variable that is assigned to any keypress
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()       
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and self.x > self.vel:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and self.x < WIDTH - self.width - self.vel:
            self.x += self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.y > self.vel:
            self.y -= self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_s] and self.y < HEIGHT - self.height - self.vel:
            self.y += self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_g]:
            if len(self.coins) < 100:
                self.coins.append(throw_coin((0,255,0), 500, 300, 15))


user = player(30, 300-32, 64,64)
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    # exit the program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    redraw_game()

pygame.quit()
```